# Bottle.py for Web Application

Tags: python, bottle

I saw bottle.py framework and found its awesome to use and works great.
But can it handle the huge traffic as it runs on single thread server but can be used to run on multi threaded server.

I want to use bottle.py for Enterprise web application with huge traffic.

Can anyone here let me know that there is no problem with bottle.py webapplication handling huge traffic.

Also it seems bottle.py version 1 hasn't been released yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with bottle.py, but the first line of [the FAQ](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/faq.html#about-bottle) says **"Bottle is a *micro* framework designed for prototyping and building small web applications and services."**

It sounds like the authors don't intend it to be used in the way you're suggesting.

Comment: I believe the term micro framework doesn't necessarily mean that it can't handle high traffic. I've used a couple of them to some extent and the term is generally used to refer to frameworks that aren't MVC and instead define functions to handle specific routes, making them ideally suited for building RESTful web services. Web.py could also be called a micro framework but that most definitely is capable of handling high traffic, having been used to build Reddit.